# How can I avoid pressing enter in Vimperator keymapping?

Tags: vimperator

I've created a key mapping to clear search highlights by pressing `.`.

```
map . :nohlsearch
```

However, pressing `.` only enters the `nohlsearch` command, requiring me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command. Is there a way to have the keybinding both enter and execute  the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<CR>` to the end, like this:

```
map . :nohlsearch<CR>
```

The `<CR>` is a "carriage return", which is the same as what pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does.

Comment: `<return>` is an alternative to `<CR>` which is a bit more intuative in my opinion! :)